# How can i create a table using the react-pdf library for generation pdf report?

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

As the react-pdf library offering some limited component and no html tag is allowed to render in reactpdfrenderer.So i am in a trouble to make table using this library?
Can any one please help me how can i create a table using this react-pdf library components?

Comment: Did you find any solution about your problem. if you find then please share with us i am also facing same issue @Nayan

Comment: Hi @Moasiz, I wrote this library to render tables in a declarative way for react-pdf.  [@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table](https://npmjs.org/package/@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table). The goal was to mimic how HTML tables are declared. Hopefully this will be usable for your scenario or give an idea of a way to approach tables in react-pdf.

Comment: Hi @DavidKucsai i install this library but not install.

Comment: @Moaiz can you please raise an issue on the GitHub repo with a few more details? And we'll see if we can resolve this.

Comment: @Moaiz I have solved the problem by using the react-pdf library's View and Text Tag. You can follow this google drive link(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wxU3xFu9GN72PgCrJr0ZCynBHPK8fU4H/view?usp=sharing).
Here you will find a sample code for generationg table using react-pdf.

Comment: Couple of resources in this ticket: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/487

Comment: @David Kucsai I have tried your library. It worked. But I would appreciate if you provide more information or explanation in the documentation, especially the props of each components.

Answer (score 16):

You can use as @David-Kucsai told in comment [@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table)

or without using

### Example

#### `Data`

```js
const data = {
  id: "5df3180a09ea16dc4b95f910",
  items: [
    {
      sr: 1,
      desc: "desc1",
      xyz: 5,
    },
    {
      sr: 2,
      desc: "desc2",
      xyz: 6,
    },
  ],
};
```

#### `app.js`

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { PDFViewer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import Table from "./components/reports/Table";
import data from "./data";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <PDFViewer width="1000" height="600">
          <Table data={data} />
        </PDFViewer>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### `Table.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Page, Document, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import ItemsTable from "./ItemsTable";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    fontSize: 11,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
});

const Table = ({ data }) => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      // ...
      <ItemsTable data={data} />
      // ...
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

export default Table;
```

#### `ItemsTable.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import TableRow from "./TableRow";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tableContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});

const ItemsTable = ({ data }) => (
  <View style={styles.tableContainer}>
    {/*<TableHeader />*/}
    <TableRow items={data.items} />
    {/*<TableFooter items={data.items} />*/}
  </View>
);

export default ItemsTable;
```

#### `TableRow.js`

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  description: {
    width: "60%",
  },
  xyz: {
    width: "40%",
  },
});

const TableRow = ({ items }) => {
  const rows = items.map((item) => (
    <View style={styles.row} key={item.sr.toString()}>
      <Text style={styles.description}>{item.desc}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.xyz}>{item.xyz}</Text>
    </View>
  ));
  return <Fragment>{rows}</Fragment>;
};

export default TableRow;
```

For more information check [Generate Dynamic PDF Invoices Using React and React-PDF](https://kags.me.ke/post/generate-dynamic-pdf-incoice-using-react-pdf/)

Comment: TLDR => used fixed width for each column across rows to emulate a table. Fantastic full example. I ended up rolling my own since the dependency route required an older version of React.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks goes to Yash for the detailed answer given. This is what I ended up creating after seeing your example.

The main trick to create a "table" is to use fixed width columns on each row.

**Note**: Make the parent container `width: '100%'` (table in this case) if you want to have your rows add up beyond 100% without overflowing/growing the parent. I would still recommend you try to have your total width add to 100% though, but the example below shows otherwise.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  table: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  row: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderTop: '1px solid #EEE',
    paddingTop: 8,
    paddingBottom: 8,
  },
  header: {
    borderTop: 'none',
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  // So Declarative and unDRY 
  row1: {
    width: '27%',
  },
  row2: {
    width: '15%',
  },
  row3: {
    width: '15%',
  },
  row4: {
    width: '20%',
  },
  row5: {
    width: '27%',
  },
})

const ReportTable = ({ data, maximumDays }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.table}>
      <View style={[styles.row, styles.bold, styles.header]}>
        <Text style={styles.row1}>Name</Text>
        <Text style={styles.row2}>Start Date</Text>
        <Text style={styles.row3}>End Date</Text>
        <Text style={styles.row4}>Days</Text>
        <Text style={styles.row5}>Info</Text>
      </View>
      {data.map((row, i) => (
        <View key={i} style={styles.row} wrap={false}>
          <Text style={styles.row1}>
            <Text style={styles.bold}>{row.lastName}</Text>, {row.firstName}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.row2}>{row.startDate}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.row3}>{row.endDate}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.row4}>
            <Text style={styles.bold}>{row.days}</Text> of{' '}
            {maximumDays}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.row5}>{row.info}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}

ReportTable.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  maximumDays: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}

export default ReportTable
```

Answer (score 2):

simple table answer here:
[showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpbbe.png)

Code:

```
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

export default function Table({ data }) {

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState();
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        rowView: {
            display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', borderTop: '1px solid #EEE', paddingTop: 8, paddingBottom: 8, textAlign: "center"
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data !== undefined) setTableData(data);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {tableData &&
                (
                    <Fragment>
                        <View style={styles.rowView}>
                            {tableData["column"].map((c) => <Text style={{
                                width: `${100 / tableData["column"].length}%`
                            }}>{c}</Text>)}
                        </View>
                        {tableData["data"].map((rowData) => <>
                            <View style={styles.rowView}>
                                {tableData["column"].map((c) =>
                                    <Text style={{ width: `${100 / tableData["column"].length}%` }}>{rowData[c]}</Text>
                                )}
                            </View>
                        </>)}
                    </Fragment>
                )}
        </>

    )
}
```

data format:

```
{
    "column": [
        "price",
        "email",
        "time"
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "price": "",
            "email": "",
            "time": ""
        },
        {
            "price": "",
            "email": "",
            "time": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

the table auto-populates based on the number of columns and auto sizes to take full page. just make sure to use column names as data keys

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkStrEmpty(str) {
return !(str && str.length > 1 && str.split(" ").join("").length > 0);
}

import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import React from "react";
 
function CustomTablePDF(props) {
const { fields = [], data = [] } = props;
let tableCol = {
    borderStyle: BORDER_STYLE,
    borderColor: BORDER_COLOR,
    borderBottomColor: "#000",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0
};
return (
    <View style={styles.table}>
        <View style={[styles.tableRow, styles.headerBg]}>
            {fields.map((_item, _idx) => (
                <View
                    key={_idx}
                    style={[tableCol, { width: _item.width + "%" }]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={[
                            styles.tableCellHeader,
                            { textAlign: "center" }
                        ]}
                    >
                        {_item.title}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>

        {data.map(
            (item, idx) =>
                item && (
                    <View key={idx} style={styles.tableRow}>
                        {fields.map((_item, _idx) => {
                            let val = item[_item.value] || "";
                            let value_alt =
                                (_item.value_alt &&
                                    item[_item.value_alt]) ||
                                "";

                            if (_item.custom) {
                                return (
                                    <View
                                        key={_idx}
                                        style={[
                                            tableCol,
                                            { width: _item.width + "%" }
                                        ]}
                                    >
                                        <Text
                                            style={[
                                                styles.tableCell,
                                                item.style ? item.style : {}
                                            ]}
                                        >
                                            {_item.component(item)}
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                );
                            } else {
                                return (
                                    <View
                                        style={[
                                            styles.tableCol,
                                            { width: _item.width + "%" }
                                        ]}
                                    >
                                        <Text
                                            style={[
                                                styles.tableCell,
                                                item.style ? item.style : {}
                                            ]}
                                        >
                                            {checkStrEmpty(val)
                                                ? value_alt
                                                : val || "-"}
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                );
                            }
                        })}
                    </View>
                )
        )}
    </View>
);
}

const BORDER_COLOR = "#000";
const BORDER_STYLE = "solid";
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
headerBg: {
    backgroundColor: "#aaa"
},
table: {
    display: "table",
    width: "auto",
    borderStyle: BORDER_STYLE,
    borderColor: BORDER_COLOR,
    borderWidth: 1
    // borderRightWidth: 0,
    // borderBottomWidth: 0,
},
tableRow: {
    margin: "auto",
    flexDirection: "row"
},

tableCellHeader: {
    margin: 2,
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: "bold"
    // fontFamily: "CustomRoboto",
},
tableCell: {
    margin: 2,
    fontSize: 12
    // fontFamily: "CustomRoboto",
},
textCenter: {
    textAlign: "center"
}
});

export default CustomTablePDF;
```

---

**use the component like this**

```
const fields = [
        {
            title: " Agent Name",
            custom: true,
            component: (item) => `${item.agent_name}`,
            width: "30"
        },
        {
            title: " Policy No",
            custom: true,
            component: (item) => `${item.policy_no}`,
            width: "35"
        },
        {
            title: "Policy Class",
            value: 'policy_class',
            width: "20"
        },
        {
            title: "Amount",
            custom: true,
            style: { textAlign: "right" },
            className: "text-right",
            component: (item) =>`${formatNumber(item.contribution)}`,
            width: "15"
        }
    ];
   
<CustomTablePDF fields={fields} data={details} />
```