# React pdf export table

Tags: reactjs, pdf

[image]

Any idea how to generate this pdf in React app with data from API ?

Comment: Check this Link it will help
[How can i create a table using the react-pdf library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373850/how-can-i-create-a-table-using-the-react-pdf-library-for-generation-pdf-report)